# Can we cancel out $1$ after replacing $e^x$ in $e^x-1$ by its Taylor expansion when calculating a limit?

Tags: calculus, limits, alternative-proof, limits-without-lhopital, substitution

So I am to prove the following formula

> $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^x -1}{x} =1$$

Now, I write,

$$
\begin{split}
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^x -1}{x} 
   &= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(1+x+x^2/2!+x^3/3!+...) -1}{x} \\
   &= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x+x^2/2!+x^3/3!+...}{x} \\
   &= \lim_{x \to 0}1+x/2 +x^2/6+...\\
   &= 1
\end{split}
$$

Is it permissible to cancel out the $1$ at the numerator  and the calculation after that? Here we are dealing with an infinite series expansion of $e^x$ ,so I am very much confused about this method.

By the way,I am not here for any other rigorous proof; I just want to know if my method is correct or not and why it is so.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes it is permissible because you are just looking at the series of $e^x-1$.

Comment: Sure. Think about it as $(-1)+1+x+\dots$ in the numerator and perhaps it easier to see that what you are doing is allowed. All of the (countably) infinite terms remaining in the numerator can certainly have an $x$ factored out so the $x$ in the denominator can be cancelled out.

Comment: Okay,but how do I know that  $1+x/2 +x^2/6+...$  -this series converges?

Comment: How do you know that **any** series converges?  Do you know the "ratio test"?  A general term in that is $a_n= \frac{x^{n-1}}{n!}$.  So $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}= \frac{x^n}{(n+1)!}\frac{n!}{x^{n-1}}= \frac{1}{n+1}x$.  That goes to 0 as n goes to infinity for all x so that series converges for all x.

Comment: In addition to convergence of $1+(x/2)+(x^2/6)+\dots$, you need to know that this sum approaches $1$ as $x$ tends to $0$. That's not obvious unless you have some theorems about power series available.

Comment: @AndreasBlass what theorem should i apply? It seems trivial though

Comment: I'd use the theorem that the functions defined by convergent power series within the interval of convergence are continuous. (That it seems trivial is one reason for my comment --- to point out that it's not trivial and needs proof.)

Comment: @Andreas I get your point .Thanks for pointing that out.
So,to get that proof fully acceptable,first I have to show that the power series is actually convegent (by the ratio test) and secondly mention the theorem that you said. Then only I can plug in the value of $x=0$ and get the final answer. Right?

Answer (score 9):

I'd suggest noticing that the limit you want to evaluate is 
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-e^0}{x-0},
$$
which is the definition of the derivative at $0$ of the exponential function. So if you know that the derivative of $e^x$ is $e^x$, then you immediately get the answer $e^0=1$.

Answer (score 5):

We know that $$\lim_{t\rightarrow0}(1+t)^{\frac{1}{t}}=e.$$

Thus, since $\ln$ is a continuous function, we obtain:
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{\ln(1+t)}{t}=\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\ln(1+t)^{\frac{1}{t}}=\ln\lim_{t\rightarrow0}(1+t)^{\frac{1}{t}}=\ln{e}=1.$$
Now, let $\ln(1+t)=x$.

Thus, $t=e^x-1$ and $$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{e^x-1}{x}=\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{t}{\ln(1+t)}=\frac{1}{\lim\limits_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{\ln(1+t)}{t}}=1.$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Substitute $$e^x-1=t$$ in your Limit-function.

Answer (score 2):

Since
$1+x \le e^x
\le \dfrac1{1-x}
$
for
$0 \le x \lt 1$
(compare terms in the power series
or see below),
and
$\dfrac1{1-x}
\le 1+x+2x^2
$
for
$0 \le x \le \frac12
$,
$1 
\le \dfrac{e^x-1}{x}
\le 1+2x
$
for
$0 \le x \le \frac12
$.

To show
$e^x
\le \dfrac1{1-x}
$,
if
$f(x)
=(1-x)e^x
$,
$f(0) = 1$
and
$f'(x)
=(1-x)e^x-e^x
=-xe^x
\le 0
$
for
$0 \le x \le 1
$
so
$f(x)
=f(0)+\int_0^x f'(t) dt
\le 1
$.